# How to retrieve or find missing pictures

Tags: data-recovery

I deleted by mistake a wallpaper to trash. I cut it out of trash and paste in to my "Pictures" folder. But now when I go to the pictures folder, the picture is nowhere. Its not even hidden. What can I do? Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a rough idea of the filename you can search your entire computer for it.

```
sudo find / -iname 'butterfly*.jpg'
```

Or if that's prohibitively exhaustive, you can do a more limited (but quicker) search of just your home:

```
find ~/ -iname 'butterfly*.jpg'
```

Comment: Thank you, is there also options if you have forgotten the file name?

Comment: @Orosjopie No good options. You could just change the search to `*.jpg` and look at all the photos. And if you can't remember the extension, you'll need to look at *jpeg, *gif and *png too.

Comment: If it is a recent action, you can probably also search for recently changed files, right?